# How to send a notification/mail to new users when they like your page

Tags: facebook, facebook-page

I have a facebook fan page, what I am aiming to happen is for when a user likes the page they receive a notification or facebook mail telling them to come and visit the page to receive their free voucher code.

However I am unsure of how to do this.

Would this be a CRON job that checks when the page receives a new user, then finds the users and user a facebook api function to either give a notification or mail?

Answer (score 0):

If could be a cron job, if Facebook allowed you to determine who likes a page.

Fortunately facebook does not allow this.

If you have an app, and a user uses your app
They do allow you to check if a particular user likes a page
however that requires the user to grant extended permissions to that app.

Your best bet is to inform people who view your page, that they can get a free voucher by subscribing to your app.

Then you can create a cron job that sends out email on new app registrations.

Comment: you might have better luck if your app checks that the user has continued to like your page for 10 days or such, but again that requires extended permissions from the user.

Comment: an app requesting extended permissions, is in most cases less likely to be subscribed to.

Comment: Mary is correct. The only way to accomplish this would be to build an app that would ask for the user's permissions. And if this is the only reason you would have for using the application, it's not really worth the while. User's don't generally like having to grant permissions frivolously.